# Python/Pandas: Search for date in one dataframe and return value in column of another dataframe with matching date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have two dataframes, one with earnings date and code for before market/after market and the other with daily OHLC data.
First dataframe df:

|  | earnDate | anncTod |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 103 | 2015-11-18 | 0900 |
| 104 | 2016-02-24 | 0900 |
| 105 | 2016-05-18 | 0900 |
| ... | .......... | ....... |
| 128 | 2022-03-01 | 0900 |
| 129 | 2022-05-18 | 0900 |
| 130 | 2022-08-17 | 0900 |

Second dataframe af:

| Datetime | Open | High | Low | Close | Volume |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2005-01-03 | 36.3458 | 36.6770 | 35.5522 | 35.6833 | 3343500 |
| ........... | ......... | ......... | ......... | ........ | ........ |
| 2022-04-22 | 246.5500 | 247.2000 | 241.4300 | 241.9100 | 1817977 |

I want to take a date from the first dataframe and find the open and/or close price in the second dataframe. Depending on anncTod value, I want to find the close price of the previous day (if =0900) or the open and close price on the following day (else). I'll use these numbers to calculate the overnight, intraday and close-to-close move which will be stored in new columns on df.

I'm not sure how to search matching values and fetch values from that row but a different column. I'm trying to do this with a df.iloc and a for loop.

Here's the full code:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests 
import datetime as dt

ticker = 'TGT'

## pull orats earnings dates and store in pandas dataframe
url = f'https://api.orats.io/datav2/hist/earnings.json?token=keyhere={ticker}'
response = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)

data = response.json()
df = pd.DataFrame(data['data'])

## reduce number of dates to last 28 quarters and remove updatedAt column
n = len(df.index)-28
df.drop(index=df.index[:n], inplace=True)
df = df.iloc[: , 1:-1]

## import daily OHLC stock data file
loc = f"C:\\Users\\anon\\Historical Stock Data\\us3000_tickers_daily\\{ticker}_daily.txt"
af = pd.read_csv(loc, delimiter=',', names=['Datetime','Open','High','Low','Close','Volume'])


## create total return, overnight and intraday columns in df
df['Total Move'] = '' ##col #2
df['Overnight'] = ''  ##col #3
df['Intraday'] = ''   ##col #4

for date in df['earnDate']:
    if df.iloc[date,1] == '0900':
        priorday = af.loc[af.index.get_loc(date)-1,0]
        priorclose = af.loc[priorday,4]
        open = af.loc[date,1]
        close = af.loc[date,4]
        df.iloc[date,2] = close/priorclose
        df.iloc[date,3] = open/priorclose
        df.iloc[date,4] = close/open
    else:
        print('afternoon')
```

I get an error:

```
if df.iloc[date,1] == '0900':
ValueError: Location based indexing can only have [integer, integer slice (START point is INCLUDED, END point is EXCLUDED), listlike of integers, boolean array] types
```

Converting the date columns to integers creates another error. Is there a better way I should go about doing this?

Ideal output would look like (made up numbers, abbreviated output):

| earnDate | anncTod | Total Move | Overnight Move | Intraday Move |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2015-11-18 | 0900 | 9% | 7.2% | 1.8% |

But would include all the dates given in the first dataframe.

**UPDATE**

I swapped df.iloc for df.loc and that seems to have solved that problem. The new issue is searching for variable 'date' in the second dataframe af. I have simplified the code to just print the value in the 'Open' column while I trouble shoot.

Here is updated and simplified code (all else remains the same):

```
import pandas as pd
import requests 
import datetime as dt

ticker = 'TGT'

## pull orats earnings dates and store in pandas dataframe
url = f'https://api.orats.io/datav2/hist/earnings.json?token=keyhere={ticker}'
response = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)

data = response.json()
df = pd.DataFrame(data['data'])

## reduce number of dates to last 28 quarters and remove updatedAt column
n = len(df.index)-28
df.drop(index=df.index[:n], inplace=True)
df = df.iloc[: , 1:-1]

## set index to earnDate
df = df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df['earnDate']))

## import daily OHLC stock data file
loc = f"C:\\Users\\anon\\Historical Stock Data\\us3000_tickers_daily\\{ticker}_daily.txt"
af = pd.read_csv(loc, delimiter=',', names=['Datetime','Open','High','Low','Close','Volume'])


## create total return, overnight and intraday columns in df
df['Total Move'] = '' ##col #2
df['Overnight'] = ''  ##col #3
df['Intraday'] = ''   ##col #4

for date in df['earnDate']:
    if df.loc[date, 'anncTod'] == '0900':
        print(af.loc[date,'Open']) ##this is line generating error
    else:
        print('afternoon')
```

I now get KeyError:'2015-11-18'

Comment: Could you post how the output should look like?

Comment: as the error tells, in `df.iloc[date,1] == '0900'` `date` is not an integer (instead I assume datetime). What do you intend to do with this line of code? Select a column / index position?

Comment: @Sandertjuhh updated for the output. Apologies for the delay.

Comment: @FObersteiner it's a conditional for whether the code should execute the code under if or the code under else. But yes, it's supposed to locate a specific row in the anncTod column

Comment: the point is, if `df['earnDate']` contains datetime objects / timestamps, you cannot use those in [iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html), you have to use integers here. There's multiple ways for selecting rows, that's why I asked what you want to do here, what problem you're trying to solve - I know what an if statement is ;-)

Comment: @FObersteiner I see, my apologies. I'm trying to locate a date from the first dataframe in the second dataframe, then return a value in that row from an adjacent column. I swapped from df.iloc to df.loc and the error is now that the code to search in the second dataframe isn't recognizing the date. I will update the question.

Answer (score 0):

To use [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to access a certain row, that assumes that the label you search for is in the index. Specifically, that means that you'll need to set the date column as index. EX:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'earnDate': ['2015-11-18', '2015-11-19', '2015-11-20'],
                   'anncTod': ['0900', '1000', '0800'],
                   'Open': [111, 222, 333]})

df = df.set_index(df["earnDate"])

for date in df['earnDate']:
    if df.loc[date, 'anncTod'] == '0900':
        print(df.loc[date, 'Open'])

# prints
# 111
```